# Optimisations with folds

Tags: performance, functional-programming, ocaml, fold

I am just curious if there are any (first order polymorphic only) optimisations with folds.

For maps, there's deforestation: `map g (map f ls) => map (g . f) ls`, and `rev (map f ls) => rev_map f ls` (faster in Ocaml).

But fold is so powerful, it seems to defy any optimisation.

Comment: you might want to post this on the theoretical CS page, too

Comment: @blueberryfields: [Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) is for research-level TCS, which this question isn't. @Yttril: Fold is a universal operation (every sequential action on a data structure can be expressed as a fold), which suggests that few such equations hold.

Comment: @Giles: yes, that's why I was curious just how many optimisations there actually are.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious ones:

```
fold_left f acc (List.map g li) => fold_left (fun acc x -> f acc (g x)) acc li
fold_right f li acc => fold_left f acc li (* if (f,acc) is a monoid *)
```

You may be interested in the classical paper on the topic, "Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes and Barbed Wire". Beware however that it is technical and has impenetrable notation.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.125

Edit: my first version of the first rule was wrong, edited thanks to vincent-hugot.

Comment: Ouch .. fold on a map, didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use deforestation on folds.  In fact, `map/map` fusion is a special case of that.

The trick is to replace list construction by a special `build` function:

```
build :: (forall b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> b) -> [a]
build g = g (:) []
```

Now, using the standard definition of `foldr`

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr c n []     = n
foldr c n (x:xs) = c x (foldr c n xs)
```

We have the following equivalence:

```
foldr c n (build g) == g c n
```

(Actually this is only true under certain, but common, circumstances.  For details see ["Correctness of short-cut fusion"](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Correctness_of_short_cut_fusion)).

If you write your list producing functions (including `map`) using `build` and your consumers using `foldr`, then the above equality can remove most intermediate lists.  Haskell's list comprehensions are translated into combinations of `build` and `foldr`.

The downside of this approach is that it cannot handle left folds.  [Stream Fusion](http://metagraph.org/papers/stream_fusion.pdf) handles this just fine, though.  It expresses list producers and transformers as streams (coinductive datatypes, kind of like iterators).  The above paper is very readable, so I recommend taking a look.

The "bananas" paper mentioned by gasche goes into more details about kinds of folds and their equivalences.

Finally, there is Bird and Moor's ["Algebra of Programming"](http://www.google.com/?q=bird+moor+algebra+of+programming), which mentions transformations such as [combining two folds into one](http://squing.blogspot.com/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html).

Comment: as I understand it fusion requires higher order polymorphic recursion, and although my language just barely manages to support Monads, it can't handle fusions ;( Maybe I got some of the terms wrong here.. +1 for ref to stream fusion paper!

Comment: There is no polymorphic recursion going on.  I don't know what *higher order polymorphic recursion* is.  However, `build` has a rank 2 type (the `forall` on the first argument).  Stream fusion in turn requires existential types (the stepper function).  Maybe you can explain more about what you are trying to do (and your setting)?

Comment: My setting is my language Felix. Primarily I'm looking for optimisations. Ideally, someone would help design a proper kinding system to allow high level optimisations like fusion.

Comment: Sorry, too brief: Felix has type schema plus some badly implemented kinding which allows some higher things to be implemented, such as Monads .. but only just. The type system is basically lambda calculus with products, functions, and type matches, but no variants. If variants could be added I think it is equivalent to a typed version of Jay's pattern calculus.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested going a bit deeper into theory, I suggest you to read something about [catamorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism), [anamorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism) and [hylomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylomorphism_%28computer_science%29). While the category theory surrounding it may seem to be a bit scary, the concept isn't that difficult.

Catamorphisms are functions that *consume* recursive data structures and produce some kind of a value. Anamorphisms are functions that given some value (a kind of a seed) *produce* recursive data structures. In particular, `foldr` and `build` mentioned in the other anwers are functions to build catamorphisms and anamorphisms on lists. But this concept can be applied to basically any recursive data structure, such as different kinds of trees etc.

Now if you build a recursive data structure with an anamorphism and then consume it with a catamorphism, you get what is called a hylomorphism. In such a case, you actually don't need the intermediate structure. You can skip creating it and destroying it. This is often called [deforestation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deforestation_%28computer_science%29).

---

Concerning `map`: This function is interesting that it's both a catamorphism *and* an anamorphism:

- `map` consumes a list and produces something; but also
- `map` produces a list, consuming something.

So you can view the composition of two maps `map f . map g` as a composition of an anamorphism (`map g`) with a catamorphism (`map f`), forming a hylomorphism. So you know can optimize (deforest) by not creating the intermediate list.

To be specific: You could write `map` in two ways, one using `foldr` and the other using `build`:

```
mapAna :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapAna f xs = build (mapAna' f xs)

mapAna' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> (b -> c -> c) -> c -> c
mapAna' f []       cons nil = nil
mapAna' f (x : xs) cons nil = (f x) `cons` (mapAna' f xs cons nil)


mapCata :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapCata f xs = foldr (\x ys -> f x : ys) [] xs
```

and the composition `map f (map g zs)` as `mapCata f (mapAna g zs)`, which after some simplifications and applying `foldr c n (build g) == g c n` results in `map (f . g)`.

Comment: Yeah I should read more. Recently went back to look at Charity.